# Array is null after assigning value to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have variable that is containing some sort of JSON data,

```
var blogData = [
                 {
                   "blogTitle":"Bangladesh",
                   "imagePath":"/img/blog/bangladesh.jpg"
                 },{
                   "blogTitle":"India",
                   "imagePath":"/img/blog/india.jpg"
                 }
               ]
```

What I want a new array **titleFilter** like:

```
var titleFilter = [
                    Bangladesh : "/img/blog/bangladesh.jpg",
                    India : "/img/blog/india.jpg"
                  ]
```

So, for this purpose, I have tried this:

```
var titleFilter = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < blogData.length; i++) {
            titleFilter[blogData[i].blogTitle] = blogData[i].imagePath;   
        }
```

**The problem is, I am getting the titleFilter array as:**

```
var titleFilter = [
                        Bangladesh : "",
                        India : ""
                  ]
```

It would be great if someone help me regarding this problem.

Comment: The result you say you want does not make sense. `[ ]` notation is for arrays, and array elements do not have labels as in your sample code.

Comment: @Pointy Extremely sorry, as I am new to JavaScript and asking something that is not clear. Is { } a valid notation for arrays instead of [ ] ?

Comment: `{ }` is for object initializers, `[ ]` is for array initializers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  this:

```js
const blogData = [
                 {
                   "blogTitle":"Bangladesh",
                   "imagePath":"/img/blog/bangladesh.jpg"
                 },{
                   "blogTitle":"India",
                   "imagePath":"/img/blog/india.jpg"
                 }
               ];
               
const result = blogData.reduce((acc, ele)=> (acc[ele.blogTitle] = ele.imagePath , acc),{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for but you can use map like this to achieve it.

```
var map = new Object(); // or var map = {};
map[blogData[i].blogTitle] = blogData[i].imagePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var blogData = [
                {
                  "blogTitle":"Bangladesh",
                  "imagePath":"/img/blog/bangladesh.jpg"
                },
                {
                 "blogTitle":"India",
                 "imagePath":"/img/blog/india.jpg"
                }
              ]

var titleFilter = {}
blogData.forEach( x => titleFilter[x.blogTitle] = x.imagePath )
```

Use this code, and you will get the desired result in titleFilter